# Google Streetview Action, different EPSG in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I'm administrating about 30 QGIS users (migrating from Mapinfo) and they want to open google streetview using an Action (through layer properties). However I'm using EPSG 3007, not Lat/Long (EPSG 3857?). I dont want to reproject.

I would like the Action to open a browser with 
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=&layer=c&cbll=57.718,11.958 (or whatever lat/long the cursor is at the moment), regardless of there being a streetview. No problem if the streetview turns out to be out of bounds and black as they likely won't try streetview out in the ocean. Streetview snaps to roads anyway, right?

I don't want to use a plugin (I know there are good ones to use), because I have several other Actions active through the Identify-tool.